# Error: ionice: ioprio_set failed: Invalid argument (while trying to build custom ROM on bash Ubuntu in Windows 10)

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ionice

I'm trying to build Resurrection Remix ROM for Asus Zenfone 2 (Z00A) in bash Ubuntu in Windows 10 Insider Preview.

I've followed [these instructions](https://github.com/ResurrectionRemix/platform_manifest).

It took me quite some time to install Java on bash Ubuntu (finally seems to work following [this manual installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre).

But now I could not pass this script error:

```
ionice: ioprio_set failed: Invalid argument
```

Even trying to figure out how to troubleshoot this error (http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/1/ionice.htm) seems it's beyond my knowledge.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you running the script as root? Also ionice should have the syntax ionice -cX -nX program-name or ionice -cX -pPID

Comment: Thanks for jumping. Yes, I'm running the build script of the ROM using sudo and the error is there... I'm not an expert, but I could search the script and the following functions invoke the ionice command:

'mk_timer schedtool -B -n 1 -e ionice -n 1 make -C $T -j$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "^processor" | wc -l) "$@"

mk_timer schedtool -B -n 1 -e ionice -n 1 \
make -C $T -j $NUM_CPUS "$@"

schedtool -B -n 1 -e ionice -n 1 `which repo` sync -j 4 "$@"'

As far I can see, the syntax used in the developer script is only ionice -nX. Could this be the error? What should I change in it?

Comment: I think that'll be ok, -n controls fine-grained io scheduling and -c is the class (like real-time vs idle). Two things to check, is selinux enabled (since it can cause really mysterious problems), and make sure that make and all those compiler utilities are installed. In this case "invalid argument" could be referring to the command to be run with non-standard ioprio. Incidentally, not much would change if you removed the ionice -n 1 bit. I'm honestly not sure what schedtool does.

Comment: Even using sudo and run bash with admin privileges in Windows, I still get: "ERROR: schedtool: Could not exec ionice - Input/output error". I have no issues or errors while running make and other compiler utilities. I've upgraded to 10352 version of Windows 10 Insider Preview without luck either. Schedtool is the latest version too. Other characteristics of my system are: HOST_ARCH=x86_64, HOST_OS=linux, HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.4.0+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty. Thanks for your help. I'm stuck with this error and can't go further on compiling...

Comment: I'm facepalming because I didn't see that you were using the new windows bash thing. It probably doesn't have a copy of ionice? Just edit the script and pull it out - so it'll be something like schedtool -B -n 1 -e make -C etc... Ionice shouldn't be necessary. Sorry for missing such a vital point!

Comment: or some kind of posix compatibility isn't working right

Comment: Thank you very much. You have not to be sorry. The process went further. Now I have a different issue. Maybe it will be better to start a new topic. So, resuming, removing the ionice command <ionice -n 1> will allow compiling in bash Ubuntu on Windows 10.

Comment: 1) Hmmm... Not working. Without the ionice part I'm getting input/output errors: `./build.sh: line 48: build/envsetup.sh: Input/output error` Trying to troubleshoot via internet and run chkdsk /R in Windows for C: and no errors found. Cannot run disk checks within bash Ubuntu in Windows 10. I'm also running both sudo and bash in Windows with admin rights. 2) Even restoring the original script with ionice -n 1 I'm getting the same error. So seems another issue with access. I'm lost, maybe VSS? Maybe antivirus low access blocking?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/498 New bug opened. Looks like something may not be implemented yet.